# How can I compare a database to an EF6 EDMX file?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework-6, edmx

We have two different databases that were *supposed* to maintained as having the same structure as one of them was being built (but naturally weren't).

We have an edmx file that was built for Database 1 (where all the changes and additions were made). There's also a bunch of unneeded crap in it that we don't want ported over to Database 2. The edmx file contains in it everything that's actually necessary. Is there any way we can compare the edmx file to Database 2 in order to see what specific object we need to port over from Database 1?

I just want to get a list of missing and different objects. From there we can port over what we need.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use some tool like Huagati DBML/EDMX Tools. It provides a very detailed report.